# How To Pass php Variable To another php file

Tags: php, variables, router

I have created a custom router. For Example

```
$istek = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch ($istek) {
    case '/' :
        $title = "Anasayfa";
        require base . 'views/index.php';
        break;
```

So I want to pass the example id variable with $_GET. But the router blocks it and redirects to the 404 page. how can I pass this variable without getting any errors or redirecting to 404?

Comment: Your code doesn't show an "example id variable", or anything throwing a 404. We also don't know what the value of `$istek` is - please edit to show more of the relevant code.

Comment: This code is the controller part. The 404 throwing section is
```default: require base . "404.php" break;```

Comment: What is the actual value of $istek if you echo it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` includes everything, not just the `/` so your switch will fail.

To fix, use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), `/` is the `PHP_URL_PATH`, whilst `?id=` would be in `PHP_URL_QUERY`.

So you could use something like this to get what you want from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

```
<?php
// example
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/controller/action?id=123';

$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$uri = parse_url($uri);

$route = explode('/', ltrim($uri['path'], '/'));
print_r($route);

parse_str($uri['query'], $query);
print_r($query);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => controller
    [1] => action
)
Array
(
    [id] => 123
)
```

https://3v4l.org/UMFQF

Comment: No this is not working. I mean how can I add this to my code? I'm beginner to the PHP so

Comment: I think now i get it. i've trying to inject the code you just send me. Thank you for your comment. ill tell when its okay.

Comment: use `switch ($route[0])` after defaulting to `/` if empty.